# Get text from data attribute on 'active' slide and update paragraph element with its value

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, custom-data-attribute, swiper.js

I've tried *(and failed)* to write some JavaScript that gets the `data-attribute` from the 'active' slide of a carousel, then adds the same text into a `p` element outside the container. When the carousel gets a new 'active' slide, the text should change - fading slightly if possible.

I don't want the caption to appear within the carousel and `overflow: hidden` prevents me from adding a caption within the slide and then positioning it outside with `absolute`.

If easier, I could get the text from a `p` within the slide rather `data-`. Then just hide the text within.

This was my attempt:

```
var caption = document.querySelector(".caption");

if(document.querySelector(".swiper-slide").classList.contains("swiper-slide-active")){
    console.log(this.getAttribute('data-caption'));
    caption.innerHTML('data-caption');
}
```

I found a CodePen using the same carousel so I thought I'd add a basic example to check what happens when the class is added/removed from the active slides.

CodePen: https://codepen.io/moy/pen/OJOyGKR

Thanks in advance, hope someone can tell me where I'm going wrong. Keen to understand JS a bit more!

Comment: The quotes you are using in your second example are not legal for strings in js

Comment: Yeah I don't know/understand any Javascript, so trying to figure it out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Swiper JS, **Events Docs**](https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api#events) has useful **Event methods** like `init`, `slideChange` etc, which are part of the **options** `on` Object.

Such event callback functions are made in order trigger a desired function once the Swiper performs an internal change. It's a way to say: *"When you do this, let me also do that"*

Here's how your JS should look:

```js
const EL_caption = document.querySelector(".caption");

function doSomethingWithActiveSlide() {
    const EL_currentSlide = this.slides[this.activeIndex - 1];    
    EL_caption.innerHTML = EL_currentSlide.dataset.caption;
}

const MySwiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
    loop: true,
    navigation: {
        nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
        prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
    },
    pagination: {
        el: '.swiper-pagination',
    },
    // Events
    on: {
        init: doSomethingWithActiveSlide,
        slideChange: doSomethingWithActiveSlide,
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks man! Quick question, I'm getting some errors in JSLint. _"'MySwiper' is assigned a value but never used."_ and _"'Swiper' is not defined."_ I can fix the first by removing `const MySwiper` and just having `net Swiper('.swiper-container', {` ...but then I still get _"Swiper' is not defined."_ ...any ideas on how to resolve that? JS file is loaded at the bottom of the HTML page and the JS file with the above in loaded after that?

Comment: I updated the CodePen with the example about but realised the captions don't seem to match the slides? https://codepen.io/moy/pen/jOYNveq

Answer (score 1):

Just replace your "Bad Code" with this

```
var caption = document.querySelector(".caption");
Swipes.on('slideChange', function () {
    this.slides[this.activeIndex].dataset.caption;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `activeIndexChange` event for this, found back at:
https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api#event-activeIndexChange

```js
var caption = document.querySelector(".caption");

var Swipes = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
    loop: true,
    navigation: {
        nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
        prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
    },
    pagination: {
        el: '.swiper-pagination',
    },
    on: {
        
        init: function() {
          updateCaptionText(this); 
        },
        activeIndexChange: function() {
            updateCaptionText(this);
        }
    }
});

function updateCaptionText(slider) {
    caption.textContent = slider.slides[slider.activeIndex].dataset.caption
}
```

```css
// external css https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.3.3/css/swiper.css
// tat for styling is from line 50 >

.swiper-container {
    width: 100%;
}

.swiper-slide {
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: 50%;
    min-height: 20vh;

    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.caption {
    background: red;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 10000;
}

// overwrite swiper defaults
.swiper-pagination {
    &-bullet {
        background-color: transparent;
        border: 2px solid #fff;
        border-radius: 50%;
        width: 12px;
        height: 12px;
        opacity: 1;
    }

    &-bullet-active {
        background-color: #fff;
    }
}

.swiper-button {
    &-container {
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    }
    &-prev {
        background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D'http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg'%20viewBox%3D'0%200%2027%2044'%3E%3Cpath%20d%3D'M0%2C22L22%2C0l2.1%2C2.1L4.2%2C22l19.9%2C19.9L22%2C44L0%2C22L0%2C22L0%2C22z'%20fill%3D'%23ffffff'%2F%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E");
    }
    &-next {
        background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D'http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg'%20viewBox%3D'0%200%2027%2044'%3E%3Cpath%20d%3D'M27%2C22L27%2C22L5%2C44l-2.1-2.1L22.8%2C22L2.9%2C2.1L5%2C0L27%2C22L27%2C22z'%20fill%3D'%23ffffff'%2F%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E");
    }
}

// GENERIC STUFF TO MAKE IT POP 
body {
    display: flex;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    font-family: "San Francisco Display Semibold";
}
.swiper-slide {
    &:before {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background: black;
        opacity: 0.4;
    }
    h2 {
        pointer-events: none;
        opacity: 0;
        color: #ffffff;
        font-size: calc(5vw);
        letter-spacing: -1px;
        transform: translateY(-5%) scale(0.8);
        transition: 1s ease;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        text-shadow: 0 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.01);
    }
    &-active h2 {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: translateY(0%) scale(1);
        transition: 1s ease;
    }
}

// This gets in apple san francisco web font 

@font-face {
    font-family: "San Francisco Display Semibold";
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    src: url(https://applesocial.s3.amazonaws.com/assets/styles/fonts/sanfrancisco/sanfranciscodisplay-semibold-webfont.eot?#iefix)
            format("embedded-opentype"),
        url(https://applesocial.s3.amazonaws.com/assets/styles/fonts/sanfrancisco/sanfranciscodisplay-semibold-webfont.woff2)
            format("woff2"),
        url(https://applesocial.s3.amazonaws.com/assets/styles/fonts/sanfrancisco/sanfranciscodisplay-semibold-webfont.woff)
            format("woff"),
        url(https://applesocial.s3.amazonaws.com/assets/styles/fonts/sanfrancisco/sanfranciscodisplay-semibold-webfont.ttf)
            format("truetype"),
        url("fonts/sanfrancisco/sanfranciscodisplay-semibold-webfont.svg#San Francisco Display Semibold")
            format("svg");
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.3.3/css/swiper.css">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.3.3/js/swiper.js"></script>
<div class="swiper-container">
    
    <!-- swiper slides -->
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
        <div class="swiper-slide" data-caption="text caption one" style="background-image: url(https://source.unsplash.com/random?sig=24);">
            <h2>Slide One</h2>
        </div>
        
        <div class="swiper-slide" data-caption="text caption two" style="background-image: url(https://source.unsplash.com/random?sig=53);"> 
            <h2>Slide Two</h2>
        </div>
        
        <div class="swiper-slide" data-caption="text caption three" style="background-image: url(https://source.unsplash.com/random?sig=52);">
            <h2>Slide Three</h2>
        </div>
   
    </div>
    <!-- !swiper slides -->
    
    <!-- next / prev arrows -->
    <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
    <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
    <!-- !next / prev arrows -->
    
    <!-- pagination dots -->
    <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
    <!-- !pagination dots -->
</div>

<p class="caption">Text Updates Here</p>
```